# Find and replace entries in an XML Phone book

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have the following XML phone book which has phone numbers beginning with 07 & 01 which I would like to replace with +447 & +441 respectively. Can anyone suggest an easy way of doing this please?

```
    <directory>
    <Entry>
      <Name>***Travis</Name>
      <extension>02089425943</extension>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <Name>***Nina</Name>
      <extension>0177377106</extension>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
  <Name>***Yusra</Name>
  <extension>07790400192</extension>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
     <Name>***Raoul</Name>
     <extension>07818838683</extension>
    </Entry>
 </directory> <directory>
```

Any help gratefully received ..

Comment: the lazy-but-easy way: `-replace '<extension>01','<extension>+441' -replace '<extension>07','<extension>+447'` or for the whole number, just do 01* and add the end tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just treat this as a plain-text replace:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\folder\phonebook.xml') `
    -replace '<extension>01','<extension>+441' `
    -replace '<extension>07','<extension>+447' |
        Set-Content 'C:\folder\phonebook.xml'
```

`Get-Content` is wrapped in brackets so that powershell reads it and then releases the file lock, without these you get an error when using `Set-Content`.

I'm using the backticks put the command onto multiple lines, this just makes it more readable than a one-liner:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\folder\phonebook.xml') -replace '<extension>01','<extension>+441' -replace '<extension>07','<extension>+447' | Set-Content 'C:\folder\phonebook.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use PowerShell's native XML support.

```
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content ".\directory.xml")
foreach($entry in $xml.directory.Entry)
{
    if ($entry.extension.StartsWith("07"))
    {
        $entry.extension = "+447" + $entry.extension.Substring(2)
    }
    if ($entry.extension.StartsWith("01"))
    {
        $entry.extension = "+441" + $entry.extension.Substring(2)
    }
}
$xml.directory.Entry
$xml.Save(".\directory.xml")

# Name      extension    
# ----      ---------    
# ***Travis 02089425943  
# ***Nina   +44177377106 
# ***Yusra  +447790400192
# ***Raoul  +447818838683
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, that's a big help. Can you tell me what the 'Substring(2)' is for? The rest of it makes sense (I think) :)

Comment: The `Substring()` method retrieves a subset of the extension starting at index 2. [String.Substring Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)